# how to get javascript variables into django url

Tags: javascript, django

```
<a href="{% url 'main:projectdata'  proname=pro.projectname  n=state   %}"></a>

<script>
   var state = 'Done';
</script>
```

how to pass javascript variable **state** into the django url in the line above when it change

Comment: This is quite vague for me to be honest. Do you just want to use the `state` variable in the Django URL or do you want the URL to be updated whenever the variable is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
var stateVar = 'Done'

var url = "{% url 'main:projectdata'  proname=pro.projectname  n=state %}".replace('state', stateVar )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).